# Software install automation

Tags: java, python, windows, deployment, installation

I work at a computer software installation center - our users run Windows. Some of the software is difficult to install for new employees. I would like to automate the setup of software using either Python or Java.  How should I fill in the information in the setup dialogs and moving through the setup process automatically?

Comment: Automating installs is a completely ordinary system administration task. Every installer I've ever used lets you specify the settings via command line and perform the installation without even displaying the GUI. All you need to do is write a batch file. Is there some reason this won't work for you?

Comment: Java would not be a language I'd choose for a task like this.  I was tempted to remove the Java tag from the question when editing, but resisted.

Comment: I would recommend to use one of the existing solution to deploy and install software. There are a OSS and commercial solutions that can do that. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @kindall, many installation systems separate the installation of software from the configuration of software.  In such systems, you can't specify settings at all (but you can edit configuration files post-install).  That said, you're spot-on correct for the ones that combine installation and configuration in one bundle.

Comment: BTW +1 for stating the **feature** you are attempting to offer to the end user (easy/automatic/invisible installation) as well as the **strategy** that you wanted to implement to achieve that (fill in the information in the setup dialogs).  The second is not necessarily the best way to achieve the first, and the first is what is *important.*

Answer (score 1):

I used [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) to automate GUIs, which should also work well for installation forms.

Answer (score 1):

---- Edited as the solution is obviously talking about Windows / MSI ----

MSI supports the passing of configuration parameters on the command line.  Look into it.  Unless they are doing something truly exotic, or they packaged the program in a way that purposefully ignores the parameters, you might find that the best solution is just to put the parameters on the command line during your chained install.

---- Original post follows ----

First, you need to know what kind of systems you are installing software on.

Then you need to select the package management system that is the default for that system, on Windows it is MSI, many Linux systems use RPM (some use deb), etc.

Then you need to look at remote installation.  Nearly every modern package manager supports one technique or another of remote installation.  Depending on the package manager, this might involve push solutions (drop the package with configuration information into a directory or send it using an interface), while others are managed with a pull solution.

If using a pull solution, install a daily job to pull from a specific resource, and then you can convert the system to a pull solution (which generally makes management a bit easier).

Later on, you may want to look at more inclusive solutions, such as how to install additions to base software during the installation process.  Again it's different for each operating system you intend to support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate dialog completions on Windows, [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit) is the way to go. Excellent documentation and support, a powerful but readable scripting language, support for custom GUI creation and script compilation, etc

Here is an WinZip installation example with AutoIt:

```
; Run the winzip installer
Run("winzip90.exe")
; Initial Setup Screen
WinWaitActive("WinZip® 9.0 SR-1 Setup", "&Setup")
Send("!s")
; Install location
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "into the following folder")
Send("{ENTER}")
; Features overview
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "WinZip features include")
Send("!n")
; License agreement
WinWaitActive("License Agreement")
Send("!y")
; Quick start
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "Quick Start Guide")
Send("!n")
; Choose interface
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "switch between the two interfaces")
Send("!c")
Send("!n")
; Installation type (custom/express)
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "&Express setup (recommended)")
Send("!e")
Send("!n")
; Select file associations
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "WinZip needs to associate itself with your archives")
Send("!n")
; Completed installation screen
WinWaitActive("WinZip Setup", "Thank you for installing this evaluation version")
Send("{ENTER}")
; Wait for winzip to load then close it
WinWaitActive("WinZip (Evaluation Version)")
WinClose("WinZip (Evaluation Version)")
```